# How to query AAD Security Group Membership from Azure SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm trying to find a way from within Azure SQL to either 1) enumerate members of an Azure Active Directory security group or 2) check if a user login is a member of an SG. I've found various articles about doing it from a domain joined standalone SQL installation but not from Azure SQL. Most of the samples for the standalone installation use system sprocs like xp_cmdshell which don't exist in Azure SQL. I know I can create an Azure Function or Logic App to sync users to a table but I'd like to avoid using an external process to do this if possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, this scenario is not supported today. You will have to talk to Microsoft Graph API from an intermediate like an Azure function to relay the data to Azure SQL Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kalyan Chanumolu-MSFT's comment should be very helpful to you. This scenario is not supported today.

You can try to use his suggestion.

> You will have to talk to Microsoft Graph API from an intermediate like an Azure function to relay the data to Azure SQL Database.

You also can [raise a support ticket to confirm it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) and also  can [put forward your suggestions in the feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Comment: Thanks @KalyanChanumolu-MSFT and Jason.  I figured it was a long shot. I'll add a suggestion for the functionality.